# There is an extra "volume" in /Volumes with a similar name to an external hdd, that persists even when HDD is disconnected

Tags: terminal, external-disk, filesystem

Here is the output of terminal with external drive connected:

```
eric@Mac f0 % cd /Volumes 
eric@Mac /Volumes % ls
Backup          Macintosh HD        Heiffer     Heiffer 1
eric@Mac /Volumes % ls -al
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel    192 Jul 18 13:49 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  wheel    640 Apr  1 12:46 ..
drwx------   1 eric  staff  16384 Jul 18 13:31 Backup
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel      1 Jul 18 13:01 Macintosh HD -> /
d--x--x--x   4 root  wheel    128 Sep 22  2022 Heiffer
drwxrwxr-x@ 21 root  wheel    782 Jul 18 13:49 Heiffer 1
```

The directory, "Heiffer 1" corresponds to the HDD in Finder named "Heiffer." The directory, "Heiffer" is visible in Finder under Macintosh HD ->Volumes->Heiffer I can only access it in Finder by using "open" in terminal.

Here is the output of terminal when the external HDD is disconnected::

```
eric@Mac /Volumes % ls -al     
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel    160 Jul 18 13:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  wheel    640 Apr  1 12:46 ..
drwx------   1 eric  staff  16384 Jul 18 13:31 Backup
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel      1 Jul 18 13:01 Macintosh HD -> /
d--x--x--x   4 root  wheel    128 Sep 22  2022 Heiffer
```

Note while I did not do it here, if I restart the computer with the external drive disconnected, the output will be the same (tried it earlier).

The data contents, about 100G, is presumably the output is from an app called touchcopy, which downloads phone data. An app I'm iffy on, but was required to use.

The data is held in small blocks with lengthy hexadecimal names.

I can and have copied all the data out of this directory, but I'd like to know where it is on my internal drive and how best to delete it, and prevent its recurrance?

rmdir fails with "Directory not empty."

Edit per comment below:

diskutil list Heiffer with drive disconnected:

```
Could not find disk for Heiffer
```

with drive connected:

```
/dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Heiffer         +4.0 TB     disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s2
                                 5AA03B6C-62E5-4C5D-9402-B5B591930AD8
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

I was able to copy the contents and delete the directory in /Volumes, but I first had to go down two subdirectories and start there with rm -R, then the next directory up, etc. to finally get it all gone.

I fully expect to have to come back here when it shows up again . . .

Comment: Your question has an answer here:
https://superuser.com/questions/20879/how-to-remove-duplicate-ghost-network-drive-on-os-x

Comment: What does `diskutil list Heiffer` show?

Comment: @Linc D. solution there helpful, thank you.

Comment: Type up a brief answer here and link back to the superuser answer as reference.  This way we can close the loop to the question and it’s better than deleting it.